# debian dependencies (libssl-dev and libncurses5)

Tags: debian, apt, dependencies

I'm trying to install under RVM the Ruby Enterpise (REE) under debian

My debian is squeeze (uname -r)

```
2.6.18-194.26.1.el5.028stab070.14xen
```

i did try to install ree but it complains that it is missing libssl-dev and libreadline5-dev. I did update my lenny to squeeze, but i didn't update the kernel, since its a production server.

**The operational system is already updated and upgraded**

sources.list:

```
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ squeeze main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ squeeze main contrib non-free
deb http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates main 
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates main
```

I did try to install it using the following command:

```
apt-get install libssl-dev libreadline5-dev
```

But unfortunately i'm getting the following problems:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  libreadline5-dev: Depends: libncurses5-dev but it is not going to be installed
  libssl-dev: Depends: libssl0.9.8 (= 0.9.8o-4squeeze1) but 0.9.8o-6 is to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

I was thinking to reinstall those packages and install again, but it has too many dependencies, and it is a production server, that i would like to know if there is any other way to fix it. Or at least to double check if it is necessary to reinstall both :-/

Comment: Are you sure that system is up-to-date? 2.6.18 is a very old kernel, squeeze ships with 2.3.32. What sources do you have (`/etc/apt/sources.list`, `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`)? `libssl0.9.8` 0.9.8o-6 doesn't exist in squeeze, you probably have some non-official sources as well.

Comment: I wasn't even aware that 2.6.18 would run on squeeze due to the new version of udev.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be no 0.9.8o-6 for Ssqueeze ([changelog](http://packages.debian.org/changelogs/pool/main/o/openssl/openssl_1.0.1c-2/changelog)), so I'd just download to 0.9.8o-4squeeze13 (higest security update for Squeeze).

`aptitude update && aptitude install libssl-dev=0.9.8o-4squeeze13 libssl0.9.8=0.9.8o-4squeeze13 libncurses5-dev libreadline5-dev -t squeeze`.

Answer (score 0):

You might to specify from which distribution to install the dependencies; `apt-get install -t stable libssl-dev` or `-t testing` might help.

I don't have enough information to go on; try showing what happens for `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*` and for `cat /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/*`